# How do I change when OS X warns about low disk space

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

I run OS X 10.6.3 with a very full hard drive, I can't upgrade it for a few months, I would like to change the warning so it warns me at around 5GB of free space, currently it seems to warn me around 500MB which is far too low. Anyone know how to increase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a user-configurable setting to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Ah well I was hoping there was a hidden setting somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you could script up your own solution and schedule it with the `launchd` daemon…

More info:
http://forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?t=110136

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to clean up your harddrive. That warning cannot be adjusted.

Well unless the dialog box is hidden inside the finder.app folder in system, but i doubt its worth tampering in there.